# Pass Unique JButton Data to Another Class on Click

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I am making a program where clicking a custom JButton allows you to make your next click paint an image at the point on the screen. Members of this JButton class have certain data that is unique to each separate button. **My question** is if I can pass the JButton object when clicked on through a method into a class which would then extract the data. I was thinking something like this:

```
Click Method in JButton{
    OutsideClass.setObject(this); //problem
}

OutsideClass{
    Object obj = new Object();
    public void setObject(Object Obj){
        obj = Obj;
    }

Click Method in OutsideClass{
        place obj;
        obj.getData;//Methods within JButton that retrieve specific data
}
```

My issue is the "setObject" part of the JButton. It doesn't recognize "this" as the specific Object clicked and thus doesn't work. Is there another way to get the desired effect? Thanks!

Comment: Instead of passing the button, pass the object associated with the button.  The rest of you code should not care where or how the object was created.  Your button will need a reference of the object/class/manager that will receive the buttons object...

Comment: I actually just solved my issue but thanks! I'm basically just making a variable to represent a way to get all the data associated with a button, not really passing the button through so to say.

Comment: You can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17463/163188).